# find data between to 2 dates in parse sdk in php

Tags: php, parse-platform

```
$query = new ParseQuery("ScannedDetails");
$query->greaterThanOrEqualTo(
    "createdAt", 
    [
        "__type" => "Date",
        "iso" => date('Y-m-d\TH:i:s', strtotime($startDate))
    ]
);

$query->lessThanOrEqualTo(
    "createdAt",
    [
        "__type" => "Date",
        "iso" => date('Y-m-d\TH:i:s', strtotime($endDate))
    ]
);
```

i have tried this but not affected ...can you help me on this

Answer (score 0):

In my case, i explicitly converted the date from my code to parse date. Then i used ParseQuery as below. I hope this will help someone. It took me 4 hours to solve this problem

```
public function convert_datetime_to_timezone($date)
        {
            $fromdate =  str_replace('+00:00', '.000Z', gmdate('c', strtotime("$date 00:00:00 ")));
            return $fromdate;
        }

$query = new ParseQuery("visitation");
                        $query->lessThan("createdAt", $fromdate);
                        $obj = $query->find();
                        var_dump($obj);
```